# OpenSuSE Leap 15.3: Update 2022-55 (1) (recommended update for audacity) fails due to missing ffmpeg-3

Tags: opensuse, ffmpeg, audacity

Every time I'd like to update my OpenSuSE Leap 15.3 (x86_64) system, the software updater in the systray stumbles upon a recommended update for audacity (2022-55 (1)). It *always* fails to get installed due to a missing ffmpeg-3 package:

> nothing provides 'ffmpeg-3' needed by the to be installed audacity-2.2.2-bp153.3.3.1.x86_64.

What's wrong here? An unresolvable dependency in a distro is somehow strange, isn't it?

**UPDATE:** These are the repos configured in my YaST:

[image: Repos]

Comment: There are a number of ffmpeg-3 packages for 15.3. They are from the base install, SLE update and from packman essentials. Bring up yast and search for ffmpeg-3 and install them before installing audacity.

Comment: Neither YaST, nor software.opensuse.org contain any ffmpeg-3 packages. :(

Comment: Your repositories are messed up, because they are there. Have you disabled them in some way?

Comment: Do you think there is a repo missing? See the screenshot above.

Comment: I've got no idea what's gone wrong with your system, but, delete the debug repos - you do not need them. As you can see in the mirror - https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/download.opensuse.org/update/leap/15.3/sle/x86_64/, ffmpeg-3 does exist. Any errors when you try and update, apart from the above? How about renaming `/var/cache/zypp` and let it rebuild the cache.

Answer (score 0):

On opensuse, `ffmpeg-3` conflicts with `ffmpeg-4. Meaning that it will not be offered or installed. If you search for it, you will see it listed, but when you choose it, you get errors.

You need to add the community repositories, specifically packman, via `yast2 repositories`.

Comment: Yep, I've got ffmpeg-4 on my machine. What I don't understand, though, is: Why does audacity require the (apparently outdated) ffmpeg-3?

Comment: Because whoever looks after it, either the audacity crew, or suse, have not bothered to update it.